# Catch and wrap runtime exceptions when creating library?

Tags: java, exception, client-library

I am writing a client library for a range of our APIs to be used by third party libraries.

There underlying http client we are using only throws RuntimeExceptions. I don't want to let these exceptions bubble up, but instead wrap them in our own ClientException.

However everything I read seems to suggest that catching runtime exceptions is really bad practice?

Is this an exception to the rule when writing libraries to be used by third parties?

Comment: Is it literally a `RuntimeException` or a specific subtype? If the latter, then there is no such *best practice* that would order you not to catch it. For example, Spring and Hibernate throw only unchecked exceptions and promote that as a *feature* and a best practice to follow.

Comment: Yes to is subtype, just an unchecked exception.

Comment: "Everything you read" isn't always geared to your specific situation (and be careful, because in many cases, especially on the internet where everybody can pretend their opinion is a credible reference source, "everything you read" consists solely of multiple statements based on the same root misunderstanding/misinformation); do what makes the most sense for your scenario and leads to the cleanest and most straightforward code (and a straightforward API). If you feel you are doing something that requires further explanation, document it clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with catching an unchecked exception, *especially* with the purpose of wrapping and rethrowing.

The only case to which an advice not to catch unchecked exceptions may apply is writing something like

```
try { ... }
catch (RuntimeException e) { ... do some handling and move on ... }
```

because that will stop any `NullPointerException`s, `IllegalArgumentException`s, etc. from breaking the execution flow. These exceptions are both too generic to be automatically recovered from (could appear at too many places, for too many different reasons), and usually indicate *programming errors* which will be more difficult to pinpoint if the code doesn't break on them.